# How to change the display text in the View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having the following tables created in my `SQL Server`:

```
Create Table tblDepartment(
    Id int primary key identity,
    Name nvarchar(50)
)

Create table tblEmployee(
    EmployeeId int primary key identity,
    Name nvarchar(50) not null,
    Gender nvarchar(10) not null,
    City nvarchar(50),
    DepartmentId int not null foreign key references tblDepartment(Id)
)
```

As you can see,

1. The `DepartmentId` column in the `tblEmployee` is the foreign key for the `tblDepartment` `Id` column. It is one-to-many relationship: each `Department` can have many `Employee`
2. Both `tblDepartment` and `tblEmployee` have `Name` column

Then in my `MVC` application, using the two tables, I automatically generate the following `EmployeeDataModel.edmx`:

[image]

(Note that I replace the name `tblEmployee` with `Employee` and `tblDepartment` with `Department`)

And naturally, I have the following auto-generated entity classes:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}

public partial class Department
{
    public Department()
    {
        this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the main `<table>` in my `Employee/Index.cshtml` `View` looks like this:

```
... using here
@model IEnumerable<Employee>
...

<table class="table" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Department.Name)</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.Name)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.EmployeeId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.EmployeeId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.EmployeeId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Note that in the table headers, I have two "Name"s:

```
<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
....
<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Department.Name)</th>
```

Which would both show "Name", fitting with the `tblEmployee` and `tblDepartment` real column names in the database. I want to avoid that, so I create a `partial class` for the `Department` to display the `tblDepartment` `Name` as `Department Name`:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(DepartmentMetaData))]
public partial class Department {
}

public class DepartmentMetaData {
    [Display(Name="Department Name")]
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

And this one is successful:

[image]

But now, I have another `View`: `Employee/Create.cshtml`:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Employee</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Gender", new List<SelectListItem> {
                 new SelectListItem {Text="Male", Value="Male"},
                 new SelectListItem{Text="Female", Value="Female"}
             }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentId, "DepartmentId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And note that I have a field for `DepartmentId` with the `DropdownList`:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentId, "DepartmentId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Just as for my `Employee/Index.cshtml` `View`, this time, I do not want to display `DepartmentId` `Label` as `"DepartmentId"`, thus I create another `partial class` for `Employee` to display `"DepartmentId"` as `"Department Name"`:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(EmployeeMetaData))]
public partial class Employee {
}

public class EmployeeMetaData {
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Department Name")] //here it is
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}
```

But when rendered, my `Employee/Create.cshtml` `View` still shows `DepartmentId` as its `Label`:

[image]

Why is that so? How can I display the `Label` as `Department Name` too?

Note: all `Views` (`Index` and `Create`) are auto generated when I create `EmployeeController` with Scaffolding option: `MVC5 Controller with views using Entity Framework`

I use `Entity Framework 6.1.1` and `VS2013` if they matter.

Comment: use dataannotations for displaying proper names

Comment: @rashfmnb I added that in my `partial class`, both for `Employee` and `Department` still the problem persists. Any idea? What I don't understand  is that it works fine in my `Index` `View` (when I add `Display` attribute for my `Department` property `Name`), but it does not work in my `Create` `View` (even after I add `Display` attribute for my `Employee` property `DepartmentId`)

Comment: have you tried 
    `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DepartmentId ) ` insted of `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentId, "DepartmentId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })`

Comment: Aren't you making it DepartmentId using the second parameter of Html.LabelFor ?

Comment: @thepanch, Cetin Basoz you nailed it. I generate it using scaffolding and so I miss to check that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentId, "DepartmentId", 
                                htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Should just be

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DepartmentId, 
                                htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Or

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentId, 
                                htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I generate it automatically by the scaffolding, so I do not realize it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `LabelFor` for the drop down control has an extra parameter, "DepartmentId", overriding the display name.  Removing that should work.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```